# guava-testlib future version JAR

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, null, guava

Today, the current Guava version seems to be:

`release is 13.0.1, August 3, 2012.`

but I checked out the source off of:

`git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/`

and got intrigued by what seems like an *extremely* useful testing tool to me:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/NullPointerTester.java

I am trying to verify that all of my methods detest `null` just as much as Doug Lea ( http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/vita.html ) seems to do, unless Joshua Bloch misquotes him ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM#t=26m35s ) in being "null-hostile".

Anyway, `NullPointerTester.java` seems to be just perfect so I am trying to build it into my project.

Following the dependencies (`NullPointerTester` -> `Invokable<?, ?>`, -> ... for example) is tedious as I run into classes that are `@since 14.0`, basically belong to a future version.

What's the best way to build a self-contained JAR of the next/future version of Guava, with all dependencies being taken care of for me? Note: the sources seem to be "all" on `git`...

---

*You can stop reading here.*

I can't wait to be doing stuff like this, which is really cool I think:

- http://www.massapi.com/class/nu/NullPointerTester.html

Note: what's missing are "security checks", as in "if the constructor has been made private, check that I cannot reflect-invoke it anyway...

If I were a better coder I'd contribute, but this is all I can do and it's very poor, although the intent should be clear?

```
static boolean isDefaultConstructorDisabled(Class<?> type) {
  boolean isDefaultConstructorDisabled = false;
  Constructor<?>[] declaredConstructors = type.getDeclaredConstructors();
  Constructor<?> defaultContructor = declaredConstructors[0];
  defaultContructor.setAccessible(true);
  try {
    defaultContructor.newInstance();
  } catch (InvocationTargetException invocationTargetException) {
    Throwable cause = invocationTargetException.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof UnsupportedOperationException
        && cause.getMessage().contains(
            ErrorMessage.DefaultConstructor.DISABLED)) {
      isDefaultConstructorDisabled = true;
    }
  } catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
  }
  return isDefaultConstructorDisabled;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cloned the whole Guava repository, then the v13.0.1 tag will have guava-testlib, and specifically NullPointerTester, as of 13.0.1, which should work -- no?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try looking in Maven?

http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-723200679

I think guava-testlib is what contains NullPointerTester.  You could grab the 13.0.1 jar.

http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1590928164

Comment: I have the `guava-13.0.1.jar` file, some dependencies of `guava-testlib`, which does not even get exported in 13.0.1, are `@since 14` though... (e.g. `Invokable`). I must admit I don't know how to use Maven beyond the basics.

Comment: NullPointerTester has been around for a while.  That 13.0.1 jar should not rely on any @since 14 things.  What you're seeing in git is the very latest, which includes changes since after the 13.0.1 release, including the one they made to have NullPointerTester use Invokable (aug 31).  Are you trying to use it in your code and it's not compiling?

Comment: Well, even if guava-13.0.1.jar is in my project (or classpath, from the CLI) I don't even "see" `NullPointerTester` on the accessible API... have you used the class in the past?

Comment: Sorry - I was trying to say that you need to download that testlib jar from that page I linked. You need guava-testlib-13.0.1.jar in addition to the main guava jar. Since you have the source checked out, see how the top level folders are named guava, guava-testlib, guava-testing etc? For each one of those there are versioned jars on maven with the compiled code. The testing utilities are packaged separately from the main release jar, which is what you have.

Comment: Also, yes I experimented with NullPointerTester several months ago. If testlib is the wrong jar then I apologize; all I did to verify before answering was that testlib jar contained its .class file.